# Why doesn't this run?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my assignment for university, it's a mp3 catalogue. But I have no idea why it does not run. The error is that there is an error in the main method. Can anyone help? Also if anyone could let me know how to add a 're-order' function to his catalogue it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class mp3catalogue
{
    // An ArrayList for storing the file names of music files.
    private ArrayList<String> tracks;
    //public mp3catalogue();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    {
        tracks = new ArrayList<String>();
        Random randomtrack = new Random();
        System.out.println("Music library loaded.");
        System.out.println();
    }

    //Next: File number to be added
    public void addNumber(int filename){
        int x = 0;
    }

    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Number of track?");
        int x;
        int number = x;
        while (number <= 1);
        String number1 = in.nextLine();
    }

    //Next: File name to be added
    public void addFile(String filename)
    {
        tracks.add(filename);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Name of the track?");
        String name = in.nextLine();
    }

    //Next: Artist to be added
    public void addArtist(String filename){
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Track artist?");
        Scanner in;
        String name1 = in.nextLine();
    }

    //Next: Duration to be added
    public void addDuration(double filename)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Track duration?");
        String name = in.nextLine();
    }

    // Next: Deleting a track
    public void removeFile(int index)
    {
        if(index >= 0 && index < tracks.size()) {
            tracks.remove(index);}
    }

    // Next: Shuffle the tracks.
    public void randomAllTracks(int index)
    {
        int trackNumber = getNumberOfFiles();
        int index1 = Random.nextInt(trackNumber);
        if(indexValid(index1)) 
        {
        }
    }

    // Next: Search for a track.
    public static int binarySearch (int[] list, int listlength, int searchItem){
        int first = 0;
        int last = listlength - 1;
        int mid;
        boolean found = false;
        while (first <= last &&!found){
        }
        return searchItem;
    }

    private int getNumberOfFiles() {
        return 0;
    }

    private boolean indexValid(int index) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: main is blank, you have to call something from it for anything to happen.

Comment: Please, please edit and format your code so that it conforms to Java standards. Coding standards make your code easier to read, and easier to understand. If you'd used correct formatting, you may have noticed that you'd written code outside of your methods.

Comment: I suppose you have missed some of the assignments before?

Comment: What is going on with all the braces all over the place?!

Comment: Really, what is the error? It should give you a message with details. Copy the whole message here. At first glance, there should be no error in `main`, given that there's nothing there.

Comment: I just edited the formatting of your code to better conform to standards. If you format your code like this (notice the indenting) you'll find it makes it much clearer and easier to follow. For future reference, you can edit your question by clicking the small "edit" link at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 2):

Because, You didn't call anything at main method.

Comment: Try to learn and run java. Good start from here, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Your main method is empty. The block is closed just on the next line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}

{
tracks = new ArrayList<String>();
Random randomtrack = new Random();
System.out.println("Music library loaded.");
System.out.println();
}
```

I think, the curly braces should be removed?

The next thing, where my eclipse throws an error, is the following line:

```
while (number <= 1);
```

It is an endless loop.

And there are a lot of empty blocks, is this really complete code?